# How to send click inputs to a background program without putting it into focus or using the cursor?

Tags: python, python-3.x, unity-game-engine, automation

I am trying to automate a tedious task in an idle clicker game (it is not competitive and scripting is generally considered fine by the community). I initially tried using AutoHotkey's `ControlClick`, but this does not work with the game. I tried creating a Python script using various methods including `win32api.mouse_event`, `win32gui.PostMessage`, `win32giu.SendMessage`, `pywinauto`, `pydirectinput` and maybe others I am forgetting.

I am able to send key presses using `pywinauto.Application` module (code below), but cannot figure out how to send mouse clicks.

```
if(__name__ == "__main__"):
    app = pywinauto.Application(backend='win32').connect(title_re="NGU Idle").window(title_re="NGU Idle")
    while(True):
        if keyboard.is_pressed("pause"): # just to exit the loop
            break
        app.send_keystrokes("w")
        time.sleep(0.02)
```

I think the issue that I am facing, is that for most programs of this sort, there is a parent controller and a child controller to which background clicks can be sent, however Unity manages things differently. Using `Window Spy`, the window has the class `UnityWndClass`. Looking around at other threads on StackOverflow and elsewhere (e.g. [Is there a way to send a click event to a window in the background in python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59285854/is-there-a-way-to-send-a-click-event-to-a-window-in-the-background-in-python)), the way this seems to be done in other programs is using `hWnd` such as below (answer in linked thread), which doesn't work since `hwnd1` is `0`:

```
def click(x, y):
    hWnd = win32gui.FindWindow(None, "BlueStacks")
    lParam = win32api.MAKELONG(x, y)

    hWnd1= win32gui.FindWindowEx(hWnd, None, None, None)
    win32gui.SendMessage(hWnd1, win32con.WM_LBUTTONDOWN, win32con.MK_LBUTTON, lParam)
    win32gui.SendMessage(hWnd1, win32con.WM_LBUTTONUP, None, lParam)

click(100,100)
```

So, is this possible? Maybe not in Python? Any leads are welcome!