# Is there a way to send mouse and keyboard clicks to a window in the background in python?

Tags: python, bots, mouseevent

so im trying to build a bot to automate some actions in a game that im running through my pc.

I would now like to be able to send a click event to the window at those coordinates, but since I would also like to do other things while the bot runs in the background I'm looking for a way to send the mouse event directly to the window (even if it's minimized/in the background), without influencing the movement of the mouse while I'm doing other stuff or bringing the window to the foreground/unminimizing it. Is this possible?

tried the this script which i found on google [Is there a way to send a click event to a window in the background in python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59285854/is-there-a-way-to-send-a-click-event-to-a-window-in-the-background-in-python)

but it doesnt work, getting errors with hwnd

and im getting this error https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ihs7i.png
and this is the code i was using https://imgur.com/JCkezsq

Comment: [ask]. Please edit your question to include what code you have and what error you are getting

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.